# How do I Bold the Second "Group By" Selection in a View?

Tags: sharepoint-views

I am trying to get the second "Group By" selection to be bold in the View (the first is by default in 2013). I tried the code posted elsewhere in a Script Editor web part and it doesn't do it. I would expect the second Group By selection would have its own CSS name or how else would it be normal when the first is bold.

.ms-gb doesn't work.

Can someone help?

Comment: It is all CSS, use the F12 inspector to find where you can hook in and then apply some CSS selectors : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: I understand F12 and that "It is all CSS", but finding the particular selector in an ASPX file of a SharePoint List View for someone who does this very rarely is not all that easy. I was hoping someone could give me the requisite CSS selector for the second Group By item and save me time I don't have (I have already spent an hour trying to find it). Not to be dismissive, but that was not an answer but a jibe to find my own answer. The CSS selector name would be the actual answer to my question.

Comment: I put jibes (I call them a stimuli-to-find-your-own-answer) in comments and answers in answers. If I have to look up and try the exact CSS it costs me 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but it works in 2010.  The second groupby item can be styled using this css class-- td.ms-gb2 a
Visited link = td.ms-gb2 a:visited 
Hover link = td.ms-gb2 a:hover

I put a custom class in a layout page and then call the same class this way:
.plusMinus td.ms-gb2 a
That way I do not effect any other SharePoint OOB stuff.

Hope this helps?
csm